# How to get the top 10 of each group in a mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sorting, limit

The question pretty much states the issue. I'd like to get the top N scoring items in each category, in a mysql query which is sorted first by group, then score. How to do this?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could show us your tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this was answered here:
[Limit the number of rows per ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217612/limit-the-number-of-rows-per-id)

Basically you get a table that contains row numbers in each partition (category) and then select records with row <= 10.